# Grouping classes in use statement

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, php-7.1

I want to use grouping construction like this:

```
use {Auth, Facade};
```

or

```
use \{Auth, Laratrust};
```

But i'm receiving an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) or \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)
```

UPD:

But if you are using something like this:
`use App\{Auth, Facade}`, everything is OK.

Comment: What php version are you using?

Comment: @Jerodev php 7.1

Comment: Can you post the complete file that gives an error here?

Comment: @Jerodev pelase, see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

You need to use `{}` to include multiple classes ONLY when you're including classes from directory.

In my case, i can just separate classes with `,`:

```
use Auth, Laratrust;
```